# Paperclip permissions error on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, ubuntu, permissions, paperclip

I can make the best kick-ass web apps all day long, but OMG I hate sys admin stuff.

```
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
Completed   in 448ms

Errno::EACCES (Permission denied - public/system/project_profile_image):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:103:in `update'

root@li182-102:/var/www/pb# ls -la public/system/
total 24
drw-rw-rw- 6 root root 4096 2011-11-13 20:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 2011-11-13 20:53 ..
drw-rw-rw- 3 root root 4096 2011-11-13 20:53 attacheds
drw-rw-rw- 3 root root 4096 2011-11-13 20:53 avatar
drw-rw-rw- 3 root root 4096 2011-11-13 20:53 background_image
drw-rw-rw- 3 root root 4096 2011-11-13 20:53 project_profile_image
root@li182-102:/var/www/pb#
```

It's complaining about permissions to a directory, but it's set to 666.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 with nginx and passenger. My first time setting this stuff up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all try `chown` your directories to the user your nginx runs under (usually `www-data`). You get the `EACCESS` error because your directories are not executable, meaning you need to set the `+x` flag for the directory Paperclip is trying to access.

```
chown -R www-data:www-data public/system # Recursively chown all directories to www-data
chmod +x public/system/project_profile_image
```

The above two lines will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant permissions to access the required directory for the system root user

```
sudo chmod 777 -R your_project_directory_to_be_access
```

In your case you can use:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R public/system/
```

For security reasons, just keep in your mind:

`chmod 777` gives everybody read, write and execute rights which for most problems is definitively too much.